# How to correctly configure Apache Camel and Spring JPA with xml

Tags: java, jpa, apache-camel, spring-data

utilI am trying to build a simple application that uses Apache Camel HL7 and Spring JPA.  Currently my Spring JPA configuration is being done through an ApplicationContext class.  Camel is being configured via xml.  My web.xml is as follows:

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

```
<display-name>Fusion Core HL7 Consumer</display-name>

<!-- location of spring xml files -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CamelServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CamelServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/camel/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>util.Startup</listener-class>
</listener>
```

and spring-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd 
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

        <import resource="camel-config.xml"/>
        <!--  import resource="jpa-config.xml"/ -->
</beans>
```

and part of the ApplicationContext:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "au.com.incarta.fusion.core.repository" })
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories("au.com.incarta.fusion.core.repository")
public class ApplicationContext {
```

I am not sure how to correctly load the ApplicationContext class.  It is quite possible that I am completely confused and that there is a better way to do all of this!

Comment: And what is your question? Maybe research a bit more on using Spring JPA. For using camel-jpa check the Camel docs, and also the unit tests of camel-jpa can be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ApplicationContext is annotated with @Configuration.

Spring will only detect this if you add the following to your spring-config.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="<your base package>" />
```